# Room database onCreate callback not called after destructive migration

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have some initial state that I need to create in my Room database.  I do so in the onCreate callback:

```
val database = Room.databaseBuilder(context, MyDatabase::class.java, "mydatabase").addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
      super.onCreate(db)
      database.myDao().initialize()
    }
  })
  .build()
```

This works great until I added a destructive migration.  All of the apps data comes from the server.  Currently there is no reason to write migrations as the app is sync'ed on login.

```
val database = Room.databaseBuilder(context, MyDatabase::class.java, "mydatabase").addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
      ...
    })
    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
    .build()
```

The problem is the the initialization performed in myDao.initialize() was wiped out and it seems that even though the migration was destructive, onCreate is not called again.

Is there a good way to handle this without writing custom migrations for each database version?

IE can I write my own destructive migration that runs for every DB version, and also calls my initialize() function?

Comment: This is strange indeed. It kind of defeats the purpose of `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` if `onCreate()` isn't called, doesn't it? I don't want to say it's a bug, but it sure feels like it. `onOpen()` is still called, though. Perhaps you can have some logic in there that populates the db if necessary.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79962330 - issue was reported to google, and it will be available in 2.2.0-alpha02

Comment: have you found any solution for this problem?

Comment: Looking at the link above, issuetracker.google.com/issues/79962330, looks like it been fixed in a newer version.  Have you tried the newest version?

Answer (score 0):

`onDestructiveMigration` is called before new tables created, so the behavior does not match `onCreate` callback.

You can call it manually

```kotlin
    
    private class Callback : RoomDatabase.Callback() {

        private var destructiveMigrationHappened = false

        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onCreate(db)
            // here is a piece of your initialization
            // ...
            // ...
        }

        override fun onDestructiveMigration(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onDestructiveMigration(db)
            // called when the tables dropped, still not created
            destructiveMigrationHappened = true
        }

        override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onOpen(db)
            if (destructiveMigrationHappened) {
                // now tables are ready, do the init stuff
                onCreate(db)
                destructiveMigrationHappened = false
            }
        }
    }
```